# Scaling Round Metric on Sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let g be the round metric on the 7-Sphere. It is given in terms of a three-Sasakian structure as follows.

\begin{equation}
g = \eta_{i} \otimes \eta_{i} + \pi^{\ast} g_{B}
\end{equation}

Basically the second term corresponds to the base of an orbibundle and the first corresponds to the fibre. As this is the round metric we know it is Einstein. Say I consider a different metric where I basically scale the 3-Sasakian structure by constants a and b.

\begin{equation}
g_{new} = a^2 (\eta_{i} \otimes \eta_{i}) + b^2 (\pi^{\ast} g_{B})
\end{equation}

I can scale the $\eta_{i}$ and $g_{B}$ such that the new metric takes a similar form to the old metric.

\begin{equation}
g_{new} = \bar{\eta_{i}} \otimes \bar{\eta_{i}} + \pi^{\ast} \bar{g_{B}}
\end{equation}

for instance

\begin{equation}
\bar{\eta_{i}} = a \eta_{i}
\end{equation}

Given the similar form of $g_{new}$ to g and the fact that g is Einstein, may I conclude that $g_{new}$ is also Einstein for arbitrary a and b?

Comment: I haven't checked in detail, but there's no reason to expect the general scaling (i.e., with $a \neq b$) to yield and Einstein metric. Up to overall scale only the fibres are being scaled (i.e., we may as well take $b = 1$). Even if we start with a _product_ metric that yields non-Einstein metrics.

Comment: I think you should add more tags, Riemannian geometry perhaps.